# Android Studio NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to convert an eclipse project to Android studio. I have installed NDK for AS and add everything needed for this project and run ndk-build which runs successfully and .so files are created as shown in image. But after running the application, It crashes with exception as shown in image well it looks for exception in same `/lib` folder and says libttsespeak.so not found. If I change `/lib` to `jniLibs` then exception changes to

```
"no implementation found for native method.."
```

[image: Android Studio error]

Answer (score 0):

some time it doest work best will be copy paste src res and other data from old eclipse project to new studio project

Comment: post your build.gradle, Android.mk and Application.mk